# Angular material stepper submission

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I have created mat stepper with 6 stages. 6 th stage is submit  .each stage consist of 7 input values & is set under a specific form group & form control . @ 6th submission the object are coming as separate for each group ,wanted to post the data as single object of all form groups.

Answer (score 0):

You must be having 6 form tags which is the reason why you are facing this issue.